# how to make a command in kivy with a variable?

Tags: image, kivy

I have been using kivy but need help with a problem. I try to run this

```
def go(self, value, value2):

    self.value2.source = 'Graphics\\Tiles\\' + value + '.png'
```

But every time it tells me value2 is not a property for newgame(my class). It works if I give the image name but I need to make it identify value2 as an argument. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending `value2` as parameter you shouldn't use `self`, like this:

```
def go(self, value, value2):

    value2.source = 'Graphics\\Tiles\\' + value + '.png'
```

The error you are getting is because `value2` is not defined anywhere else on your class.